# Can't get audio to work in three.js, am I missing something obvious?

Tags: audio, three.js

I'm trying to get a song to play from an object in my scene, and I simply cannot get it to work. I've made the most basic example possible to try and work out why it won't play but I still do not know.

What I've done is set up an entirely new scene, added a cube to it, and then copied the example from the ThreeJS documentation (where I've exchanged the audio file to a local one obviously), which follows:

```
// create an AudioListener and add it to the camera
var listener = new THREE.AudioListener();
camera.add( listener );

// create the PositionalAudio object (passing in the listener)
var sound = new THREE.PositionalAudio( listener );

// load a sound and set it as the PositionalAudio object's buffer
var audioLoader = new THREE.AudioLoader();
audioLoader.load( 'cold.mp3', function( buffer ) {
    sound.setBuffer( buffer );
    sound.setRefDistance( 20 );
    sound.play();
});

// create an object for the sound to play from
var sphere = new THREE.SphereBufferGeometry( 20, 32, 16 );
var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { color: 0xff2200 } );
var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( sphere, material );
scene.add( mesh );

// finally add the sound to the mesh
mesh.add( sound );
```

The audio file "cold.mp3" plays as intended if I listen to it on my PC, but the code I have written simply won't. Could the issue lie in it being stored locally or am I missing something else here?

Comment: Are you aware that automatic audio playback requires user interaction? Does it work if you have a similar starting screen like in this example? https://threejs.org/examples/webaudio_timing

Comment: I wasn't, no. I have tried doing this now. The way it currently works is there is a button that I need to press, and upon doing this it renders my sphere in the middle of the scene and starts rotating it. It it also supposed to start the audio file, which it still does not. I replaced my .mp3 file with another shorter .mp3 file just in case there might be an issue there, but to no avail.

What else could be causing the issue? I've tried different browsers too, so it has to be a problem with the code.

Comment: Any chances to share your code as a git repository? Or maybe as an editable live example?

Comment: Of course. The code is available through this link: https://codeshare.io/5OPpej

Comment: I've tested your code on my computer it everything works fine. Notice that I have hosted the `html` file on a local web server. Are you also doing this?

Comment: I'm not, I've been running it offline in the browser by simply opening up the link. I just tried hosting it on a local web server through Node.js and it solved the issue! I've been going mad trying to find the reason as to why it doesn't work. Thank you so much for helping me sort this out, Mugen87!